# In ckeditor version 4.0 extra plugin not working

Tags: laravel-5, plugins, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

i am trying to add extra plugin(colorbutton) in ckeditor 4. i also add color button in plugin folder and also add config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton'; in config.js.

but apply after this method it gives error and dont show ckeditor.
ERROR :- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getEditor' of undefined

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example so that others can reproduce your error.  See here for more details- https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve